# Templating - Get a string of the entry's field handle

Tags: macro

I'm passing entry fields into a macro and I'd like to be able to get a string of the field handle

```
myMacro(entry.field1)
myMacro(entry.field2)

{% macro myMacro(entry) %}
  {# I want a string of 'field1' here #}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do it that way because `entry.field2` will return you the normalized field value and there is no way to trace back some object|string|variable to an unknown entry with an unknown field handle. You need to pass the handle as a second parameter in your macro

```
{% macro myMacro(field, fieldHandle) %}
    {{ fieldHandle }}
{% endmacro %}

myMacro(entry.field2, 'field2').
```

You could also pass the entry and a field handle instead of the field

```
{% macro myMacro(element, fieldHandle) %}
    {{ fieldHandle }}
    {% set value = element.getFieldValue(fieldHandle) %}
{% endmacro %}

myMacro(entry, 'field2').
```

Comment: I had been passing the string in the macro, but was hoping to eliminate that as a requirment. I dig your second approach, I hadn't thought of that, but I'd be worried the loss of clarity may not be worth it in the long run. Cool all the same.

Comment: Well... You have an object and you have an index, when you pass only the elements value you can't know what the corresponding index is. However - depending on the macro you should not lose that much insight just because you pass a handle